# Flutter requires SDK version

Tags: flutter

I have this error:

```
Running "flutter packages upgrade" in bingo360...               
The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.2-dev.0.0.flutter-0a7dcf17eb.
Because bingo360 depends on flutter_launcher_icons >=0.7.1 which requires SDK version >=2.2.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub upgrade failed (1)
```

My pubspec.yaml is:

```
environment:
sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
http: ^0.12.0+1
flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.2"

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
  sdk: flutter
```

I try to change to `sdk: ">2.2.0 <3.0.0"` but not works.

Any suggest?

Comment: Make sure your flutter is up to date. Run `flutter doctor -v`. That prints the version of Dart included with that version of flutter. Make sure that the Dart version is at least 2.2. (The current version of Dart, with flutter 1.5.4 beta, is 2.3.0)

Comment: @RichardHeap dart version is 2.1.2 and flutter is 1.2.1. how to update it?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading

Comment: @RichardHeap thanks, this is my first project using flutter

Comment: ```flutter upgrade```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Go to 'Tools' -> Flutter -> 'Flutter Upgrade'

See if that works it out. If it's the SDK that needs upgrading you can't manually alter it

Comment: Mine is at the latest flutter version, still keep getting such failures

Comment: What gets printed when you run Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Doctor? Or in terminal: flutter doctor -v

Answer (score 52):

do this on your terminal :

```
flutter upgrade --force
```

Comment: I did this, waited for about 30 minutes, still same error, upgrading does not work.
Because timeago 3.0.2 requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0 and no versions of timeago match >3.0.2 <4.0.0, timeago ^3.0.2 is forbidden.

Answer (score 4):

in pubspec.yaml - I resolved the issue by:
Changing the: Environment variable to  1 point below what the SDK was requesting - for example the SDK was requesting 2.15.0 - I adjusted to 2.14.0 and run put get and then pub upgrade-
**environment:
sdk: ">=2.14.0-144.0.dev <3.0.0"**
Also ensure that in File>Settings-> Languages and FrameWorks->Dart that the Dart SDK is set properly - it usually is inside of the flutter\bin folder

Answer (score 3):

Use this command system will be auto find match version of your project.

```
flutter pub add flutter_launcher_icons
```

Answer (score 1):

Find your flutter sdk's location. In my case its
`C:\src\flutter` and run the command

`C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color upgrade`

OR

Go to
`Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Upgrade`

[Click to see screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWGtP.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in **Visual Studio Code** then just create a new flutter app

```
flutter create foo
```

and copy and paste the sdk range from the new **pubspec.yaml** file to your current project.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.0-116.0.dev <3.0.0"
```

The above solution did not work for me but this did.
However, please make sure that all your packages from **pub.dev** are up to date if you are not strictly developing based on an old package, otherwise it might cause error and you have to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

try this for mac

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the SDK version to the required one in the error. For example, in your case to >=2.1.0 <3.0.0 in the "pubspec.yaml" file.

Answer (score 1):

i got the same error and `flutter channel beta` then `flutter upgrade` work for me

Answer (score 0):

Close any code editor that might be using the SDK(VScode or Android Studio example).
Find powershell and run as Admin.
Type in the command - choco upgrade dart-sdk. This fixed my problem. I was able to run pub get without any errors.

Check out the source.
https://dart.dev/get-dart

Answer (score 0):

Sdk location is the problem in most cases,

sdk must stay in C drive straight not inside many other folders try to keep it simple as c:\flutter and update your path environment variable.

Restart you IDE it should work fine .

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to upgrade:
Downgrade the version of the package you are using.

I wanted to use `google_mobile_ads:^2.0.1`.

But I got the same error. I used `google_mobile_ads:^1.0.1` instead.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the following error:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.19.0-146.2.beta.

Because app depends on http >=0.13.6 which requires SDK version >=2.19.0 <3.0.0 or >=3.0.0 <4.0.0, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in app...                                  
pub get failed
command: "/Users/user/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart __deprecated_pub --verbosity=warning get --no-precompile"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "/Users/user/development/flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "/Users/user/.pub-cache",
}
exit code: 1
last line of pub output: "Because app depends on http >=0.13.6 which requires SDK version >=2.19.0 <3.0.0 or >=3.0.0 <4.0.0, version solving failed."
```

For me, changing the channel from dev to stable and then upgrade helped. Finally `flutter pub get` worked.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was (Windows OS):

I run command shell as an administrator:

```bash
flutter upgrade --force
```